# Always Status Code is coming 401

Tags: android, basic-authentication, multipartform-data

I am doing one form post with basic authentication but always the status code is coming 401.

```
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

  MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();        
  builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

  builder.addPart("picture", new FileBody(new File(picture)));
  builder.addTextBody("firstName", firstname);
  builder.addTextBody("lastName", lastname);

  String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic "   +Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
  Log.d("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials);

  httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials);
  httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());

  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

But it's working perfectly in the browser (Advance rest client), please kindly go through my code and suggest me some solution.

Comment: What happens if you use your details and post them to the url using a REST client like Postman?

Comment: status code is coming 200ok but from the app it's coming 401

Comment: Can you try with Base64.DEFAULT when you are doing encodeToString?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the http request that you're sending with the one that PostMan is sending using a tool like Feedler and see what you're missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic "   +Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

instead of

```
String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic "   +Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```